# Is there a word for someone who likes wood?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a person who has a passion for wooden stuff, and prefers everything made of wood, trying to fill their surrounding  with wooden objects (the chairs, stairs etc).

something like:

- Wood-lover
- Wood-passionate

Do we have such a word?

Answer (score 8):

## *xylophile*

The OED mentions *xylophilian* in its *xylo‑* entry as referring to “one of a tribe of beetles (*xylophili*) whose larvæ live on decayed wood”, so you can use ***xylophile*** for your purposes. This word combines two familiar elements from Ancient Greek:

- The classical prefix [*xylo‑*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/xylo-) as in English *xylem*, from Ancient Greek ξύλον (xúlon, “wood”).
- The classical suffix [*‑phile*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-phile) from  Ancient Greek φίλος (phílos, “dear, beloved”).

## *lignophile*

If you are into combining classical elements of differing pedigrees, instead of using Greek *xylo‑* for the prefix to match up with Greek *‑phile*, you could instead use the Latin-derived [*ligno‑*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ligno-) element, from Latin *lignum* “wood”, and compose thereby ***lignophile***, or perhaps ***ligniphile***.

That one I could find no citations for, but its meaning would be obvious. That’s because in English, particularly in scientific or technical English, we are allowed to mint new words from classical roots whenever it suits our fancy.

### Other possibilities

If you didn’t mind going further afield, then for a figurative, extended sense you could allude to matters *sylvan* or *arboreal*, although those technically mean “of the forest” and “of the tree(s)”, respectively, not “of wooden products” which you seem to be seeking. Nevertheless both those words could surely provide you with a corresponding Latin-derived prefix if you wanted one, and the result might even be more readily recognizable than the existing xylophilian examples to the less lettered of your readers.

But it’s not like any of these fancy-sounding terms are better for the job than *wood-loving* as an adjective and *wood-lover* as a noun; they just falute higher is all.

Comment: uh, you're a xylophile too.

Comment: @tchrist 'allowed to mint new words from classical roots whenever it suits our fancy', I've made a special note of that.

Comment: note that of cellulose, xylem, and lignum; lignum is the most 'woody'

Answer (score 0):

Wood-enthusiasts is one possibility